# Microsoft DNX application Angular2 does not run when deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, angular, dnx, dnx50

I have followed this tutorial describing how to build an ASP.NET MVC app using Angular2 and typescript https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/

**App deployed locally**

I made it run on my local machine (Kestrel) after some changes such as the version of the libraries

[image: Local deployment on Kestrel works]

---

**App deployed on Windows Azure does not display the menu**

Unfortunately, deploying the same application on Windows Azure does not display the menu on the index page:

- http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net/index

Here are the pages linked to the menu (that is not showned on azure)

- http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net/sub
- http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net/numbers

[image: App deployed on Windows Azure does not display the menu]

[image: Publish web - settings]

** Bear in mind that there is no error on the browser**, all logs from firefox, internet explorer, chrome and opera do present the same page

Do you have any idea where I need to look at?

**app.componennt.ts source file**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {AsyncRoute, Router, RouteDefinition, RouteConfig, Location, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {StaticComponent} from "./components/static.component";

declare var System: any;

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "/app/app.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public routes: RouteDefinition[] = null;
    constructor(private router: Router,
        private location: Location) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.routes === null) {
            this.routes = [
                { path: "/index", component: StaticComponent, name: "Index", useAsDefault: true },
                new AsyncRoute({
                    path: "/sub",
                    name: "Sub",
                    loader: () => System.import("app/components/mvc.component").then(c => c["MvcComponent"])
                }),
                new AsyncRoute({
                    path: "/numbers",
                    name: "Numbers",
                    loader: () => System.import("app/components/api.component").then(c => c["ApiComponent"])
                })
            ];

            this.router.config(this.routes);
        }
    }

    getLinkStyle(route: RouteDefinition) {
        return this.location.path().indexOf(route.path) > -1;
    }
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "marketresearchio",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "The simplest way to find public Market Research Reports",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "Market Research"],
  "projectUrl": "https://marketresearchio.net",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "listFiles": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "diagnostics": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",

    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/ambient/jasmine/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

**global.json**

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a `500 Internal Server Error` when visiting that site in Firefox.

Comment: @Brad, it is up again

Comment: The `*ngIf="routes != null"` expression is equating to false so you're navbar items aren't showing.  Can you confirm your code for `app.component.ts` is the same as from the tutorial.

Comment: @Brad, I confirm that the app.component.ts is similar to the tutorial, see the source code inside the question

Comment: here are the files that I visual studio want to deploy. I don't see the Views/* files ?!?

  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/udwin.png
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNO2Z.png
  [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xTEDc.png

Comment: I don't think you have a problem with missing files.  Log to the console in the `ngOnInit()` function to see if it's being called and that the `routes` property is being assigned.  Also try initialising the `routes` in the constructor instead of the `ngOnInit()` function just to see if it works.

Comment: @brad, indeed the files are stored on the server in another directory, I checked on the ftp server

Comment: @brad, I have initialised the routes inside the constructor, unfortunately the menu aren't showned. I have added 2 links in the question linking to http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net/sub and http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net/numbers

Comment: Try setting up the routes using the `@RouteConfig` decorator on the `AppComponent` class and hard code the router links in the template.  Use [the angular router docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) as a guide.  I'm not sure why the tutorial is setting up routes in this manner but it may be a compatibility issue because the tutorial is using angular.beta.0.

Comment: @brad I tried to use the @ RouteConfig solution but I don't know how to get the active routes and assigne the variable 'routes'. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

the minification of router.dev.js broke the app from day 1!

I have changed the code to do load the un-minified versions of all javascripts

thanks to @Brad for the support!