# Angular2/Azure/Visual Studio Attach debugger : JavaScript runtime error "pRAseInt" is undefined - angular2-polyfills.min.js

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, dnx, polyfills

I run my Microsoft DNX app that works on my local iispexpress and kestrel web servers. See [Microsoft DNX application Angular2 does not run when deployed on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464020/microsoft-dnx-application-angular2-does-not-run-when-deployed-on-azure)

### Reproduce the error

1. I attach the "Azure" debugger on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

[image: Visual Studio Update 2 - Microsoft Azure - Attach debugger]

2. The app starts http://marketresearchio.azurewebsites.net
3. error messages are displayed on the Debug output screen
4. a popup displays the error message : "JavaScript runtime error "pRAseInt" is undefined - angular2-polyfills.min.js"

[image: Angular2-polyfills - JavaScript runtime error "pRAseInt" is undefined - angular2-polyfills.min.js]

---

### Conclusion

**I made a search on my server and there is not a single occurrence of pRAseint inside the files**

Do you have any idea where there error could come from?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using non minified files? `pRAseint` really looks like `parseInt` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes from Glimpse : https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype/issues/94